# Doctrine 2: error mapping relation from Sql Server tables with spaces in field's names

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm

**This is the stage**:

Linux debian with Symfony2.5.6/Doctrine2 connected to Sql Server via (FreeTDS DB-lib).

[intellectsoft-uk/MssqlBundle Driver](https://github.com/intellectsoft-uk/MssqlBundle) installed and running ok.

Two SQL Server related tables with `spaces` in Table/Field names (sorry, i can't post images):

```
´
dbo.MYCOMPANY$Item
    No.         - varchar(32)
    Description - varchar(32)

dbo.[MYCOMPANY$Item Variant]      
    Code         - varchar(32)    
    Item No.     - varchar(32)
´
```

**Note**: Yes... it's a horrible naming style, Dynamics Nav and microsoft are the offenders.

---

Two Doctrine's entities mapping this tables with a `OneToMany` relation pointing to `Item Variant` entity from `Item` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="dbo.MYCOMPANY$Item")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Item
{
    /* @ORM\Id 
     * @ORM\Column(name="[No_]", type="string", length=32) 
     */
    private $no;

    /**
    *  @ORM\Column(name="Description", type="string", length=128) 
     */
    private $description;

    /* @ORM\OneToMany(
     *     targetEntity="DymamicsBundle\Entity\ItemVariant", 
     *     mappedBy="item", cascade={"persist","remove"}) 
     */
    private $itemVariants;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="dbo.[MYCOMPANY$Item Variant]")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ItemVariant
{
    /* @ORM\Id 
     * @ORM\Column(name="Code", type="string", length=32, nullable=false) 
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(
     *    targetEntity="DymamicsBundle\Entity\Item", 
     *    inversedBy="itemVariants")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(
     *     name="[Item No_]", 
     *     referencedColumnName="[No_]", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $item;
}
```

In a controller i query for an item XXXXXX:

```
/** @Template() */
public function helloAction($name)
{
    $item = $em->getRepository("DynamicsBundle:Item")->findByNo('XXXXXX');
    return array('item' => $item);
}
```

In the `index.html.twig` template i print the fields without problems:

```
{% block content %}
    {{ item.no }}
    {{ item.description }}
{% endblock %}
```

---

**... And now the problem:**

If i try to access to the member `itemVariants`...

```
{% block content %}
    {{ item.no }}
    {{ item.description }}

    This item has {{ item.itemVariants.count }} variants
    {% for v in item.itemVariants %}
        <p>{{ v.code }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

I get **this fatal error**:

```
> 
> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
> ("Unrecognized field: t0.[Item No_]") in
> .../DynamicsBundle/Resources/views/Demo/index.html.twig at line 2.
>
```

**One tested solution** (non-viable for me, since i can't modify Dynamics Nav database fields):

Renaming the `Item No.` field in the table `dbo.[MYCOMPANY$Item Variant]` by... i.e. `ItemNo`... problem resolved:

```
class ItemVariant
{
    ...
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(
     *     name="ItemNo", 
    ...
    private $item;
}
```

The output:

```
This item has 2 variants
red
blue
```

Accordingly... the problem seems to be the `Item No.` field name

I tried to change this parameters in the SQL Server database:

```
ANSI_NULLS ON
ANSI_PADDING ON
ANSI_WARNINGS ON
ARITHABORT ON
QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
```

... but nothing

¿Any suggestion? Thx...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use ` in table and field names (in annotations)?

Comment: Yes, i've tried to change brackets for character ` ( ` Item No_`   instead of [Item No_] and so on...) but still have the same problem.

Comment: How about combine ` and [ ?
Last thing what you can do is create views for tables with spaces in names or column names which will change the names to DoctrineReadable form.

Comment: Hi Karol, same problem. I need to find a solution because i've spent many hours looking for a solution and especially because there are many tables in the database to convert and maintain them in views.

Comment: How many tables, 50? or 500? Maybe time spent on writing create view sqls and refactoring code to operate on views it's better solution than research? Have you tried @ORM\Table(name="\`dbo.[MYCOMPANY$Item Variant]\`") something like this?

Comment: no. The original problem persist. My interim solution was to convert every table into a view as you recommended me, but using tables directly is impossible with fields with spaces.

Comment: Maybe problem exists in Driver Bundle, fork and fix :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Quote from [Doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html#identifier-quoting-and-legacy-databases):

> You cannot use non [a-zA-Z0-9_]+ characters, they will break several SQL statements.
>
> Having problems with these kind of column names? Many databases support all CRUD operations on views that semantically map to certain tables. You can create views for all your problematic tables and column names to avoid the legacy quoting nightmare.

So the space in column name "Item No." is the source of problem encountered.
Or more specifically, here is [the line of code](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.5/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/Entity/BasicEntityPersister.php#L1696) prevent join column from having space " " character.

So create views for those tables as suggested by @Karol and @xhostar is the recommended way.